# Removing unnecessary space

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup

```
<div class="middle-content">
    <div class="red-div">
        <div class="tex-area">
            <h4>First Header</h4>
            <p>Some random paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="white-div">
      <div class="tex-area">
        <h4>Second Header</h4>
        <p>Some random paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The following styling

```
.middle-content {
        overflow:hidden;
        display:block;
    }
    .middle-content .red-div {
        height: 150px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    .red-div .tex-area
    {
        margin:-50px 0 20px 130px;
    }
    .middle-content .white-div {
        height: 150px;
        background: white;
    }
```

The desired output should be.

[image]

But I'm getting

[image]

As you can see I've got white space which I don't know where it's coming from. Does anyone know how to get rid of this white space? I can't seem to figure out how the space is being generated

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hint : it either comes from a margin or a padding.

Comment: You code does not generate anything that looks like the supplied images. - http://jsfiddle.net/mu9u3g8e/ Have you used a CSS reset?

Comment: @Paulie_D No I haven't

Comment: Then try googling CSS Reset and I think you will find the answer you are looking for. Headings and paragraps have built in margins/padding that sometimes need to be removed.

Comment: @Paulie_D Ohh ok, thanks I will have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to browser's default styles, set

```
h4, p {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `line-height` 90% or less

```
.red-div { line-height: 90%;}
.white-div { line-height: 90%;}
```